# How to add and set a new default (active) product tab on the WooCommerce product page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce plugin under WordPress platform, and I'm trying to change the default tab in `single-product.php` page.

[Link to my website](https://vps1420.secured-cloud.net/product/test/#reviews)

So right now I'm having the second tab active, I want to change the first tab to become the default active tab.

I have changed priority using `woocommerce_product_tabs` filter hook like that:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', function($tabs) {
    global $post, $product;  // Access to the current product or post
    
    $custom_tab_title = get_field('props', $post->ID);
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 10;
    if (!empty($custom_tab_title)) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title('props')] = [
            'title' => 'אביזרים',
            'callback' => 'awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs',
            'priority' => 5
        ];
    }
    return $tabs;
});
```

And I have also tried changing it using jQuery basing on class `active` like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log( "ready!" );
    jQuery('.reviews_tab').removeClass('active');
jQuery('#tab-title-awp-props').addClass('active');
});
```

Nothing worked so far.

How can I change default active tab in WooCommerce single product page?

Comment: Maybe try by triggering a click event: `jQuery('#tab-title-awp-props').trigger('click');`

Comment: @David unfortunately didn't worked. As I followed the page loading process using lighthouse I saw the page is ready before the tabs are really loaded, so it's affecting the javascript functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`woocommerce_product_tabs`** hook you are using is correct and the function too. It is used inside the template: `/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php`.

However, the callback function is missing.

You can find complete examples here:

- [Editing product data tabs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/)

**To set a new product tab as default** you will then need to use the following (complete) code:

```
// adds and sets a new default product tab on the product page
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_new_default_product_tab' );
function add_new_default_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;

    // set the new priority to the "reviews" tab
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 10;

    // gets the value to use as the title and slug of the new tab
    $custom_tab_title = get_field( 'props', $product->get_id() );

    // if the custom field is set, it adds the new tab
    if ( ! empty($custom_tab_title) ) {
        $tabs['awp-' . sanitize_title($custom_tab_title)] = array(
            'title' => 'אביזרים',
            'callback' => 'awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs',
            'priority' => 5
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}


// create the content of the new tab
function awp_custom_woocommerce_tabs() {

    // the new tab content

}
```

> `props` is assumed to be a custom field added via the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin.

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer.
Some thing is still missing though, I can't seems to get this working. since `$custom_tab_title` returns Hebrew language value, jquery is returning error, so I changed it back to props. but I'm still getting the second tab active as default. Why is that?

Comment: Wasn't noticing the URL had #reviews in it somehow.. so it allways redirected me to reviews.